# Typing Unicode characters into Texmaker editor on Linux Fedora

Tags: fedora, unicode, latex

I have Texmaker and TexLive running on Linux Fedora and I would like to be able to directly insert in its editor Unicode characters (e.g. ՝ ) not present on my keyboard. In Linux this can be made with the keyboard combination `ctrl + shift + u`, then typing the Unicode code (055d for my previous example). However, this does not work in the editor (only there, in any other program that works just fine) and I am forced to copy and paste special characters from its outside when I need them.

Since with my past Windows OS I was able to do so (it just doesn't work now on Linux) am I missing some settings in Texmaker or in my current OS? What can be done?